# Does the improper integral $\int\limits_0^{+\infty}x^p\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x,~~p>0$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

> Does the improper integral $\int\limits_0^{+\infty}x^p\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x$ for $p>0$ converge?

*Attempt.* Limit of $x^p\sin x$ as $x$ tends to $+\infty$ does not exist, in order to guarantee integral's divergence. So I worked on the definition. For $p=1$ we get the integral: 
$$\int\limits_0^{+\infty}x\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{x\to +\infty}(\sin x-x\cos x)$$ (after integration by parts), which does not converge (the limit does not exist). This approach also works for $p>1$, but I had difficulties regarding the case $p<1$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use $x^p-(x+\pi)^p = \int_x^{x+\pi} p y^{p-1}dy\sim p x^{p-1}$ to find the asymptotic of $\int_0^T x^p\sin(x)dx$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If that integral converged, then as $n\to \infty$ through integer values,

$$\int_{2\pi n}^{2\pi n + \pi} x^p\sin x\, dx\to 0.$$

But this integral is greater than

$$(2\pi n)^p\int_{2\pi n}^{2\pi n + \pi} \sin x\, dx = (2\pi n)^p\cdot 2 \to \infty,$$ contradiction.

Comment: Again, you manage to avoid the calculations. Very nice.

Comment: Your integrand is $x^p\sin x$ and intervals are $[2\pi n, 2\pi n+\pi]$ for each $n\geq 1$. But on some of these intervals $\sin x$ is negative so you cannot say that this integral is greater than ..., Instead consider the same integral but with limits $4\pi n$ and $4\pi n+\pi$ where $\sin x\geq 0$.

Comment: @ZFR For each positive integer $n,$ $\int_{2\pi n}^{2\pi n+\pi}\sin x\,dx =2.$ I'll edit the first line so it's clear that $n\in \{1,2,3, \dots\}$ for each $n.$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
&\int_{0}^{M}x^{p}\sin xdx\\
&=-M^{p}\cos M+p\int_{0}^{M}x^{p-1}\cos xdx\\
&=-M^{p}\cos M+p\int_{0}^{1}x^{p-1}\cos xdx\\
&~~~~~~~~+pM^{p-1}\sin M-p\sin 1-p(p-1)\int_{1}^{M}x^{p-2}\sin xdx.
\end{align*}
The term $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}x^{p-2}\sin xdx$ is absolutely convergent for $0<p<1$. But the term $-M^{p}\cos M+pM^{p-1}\sin M$ has no limit as $M\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: So are you restrcited to the case $0<p<1$, right? But what if $p>1$?

Comment: @ZFR, I think you can perform integration by parts several times to get $x^{p-r}\sin x$ or $x^{p-r}\cos x$ so that $0<p-r<1$, and then proceed the above argument.

Answer (score 1):

I will repeat (not verbatim) an argument another user made here, which for some reason he deleted but I don't know why (it seems correct to me). There might be some mistake in this argument, and if so feel free to let me know.

There exists an absolute constant $C>0$ and infinitely many disjoint compact intervals $\{I_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ of length $C$ in $(1, \infty)$ such that $\sin(x) > \frac{1}{2}$ whenever $x \in \bigcup_{n} I_n$. Now put $g(x) = \int_{0}^{x} t^p \sin t \ dt$ where $p>0$ is arbitrary. If $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)$ exists, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} g(\sup I_n) - g(\inf I_n) = 0$, but this is absurd since $g(\sup I_n) - g(\inf I_n) \geq \frac{C}{2}$ for each $n$.

Comment: But, there exists $O : = \{ J_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ where $-1/2 < sin x < 0 $ for all $x \in J_n$.

Comment: @MarceloNg That doesn't really matter. A necessary condition for $\int_{0}^{+\infty} f(x) \ dx$ to converge is that for any functions $g,h:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}_{+}$ with $g(n), h(n) \xrightarrow{n \to +\infty} +\infty$ we have that $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_{g(n)}^{h(n)} f(x) \ dx=0$$

and here the condition is violated taking $g(n) = \inf I_n$, $h(n) = \sup I_n$.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the Dirichlet's test, then there is an easy argument: suppose that $\displaystyle{\int^{+\infty}_{0}} x^p\sin x{\rm d}x$ converges, then since $\dfrac{1}{x^p}$ monotonally decreases to $0$ on $[1,+\infty)$, the integral $\displaystyle{\int^{+\infty}_{1}} \sin x{\rm d}x$ must also converge, but it does not.